# RubyMine: exclude specific files from search

Tags: rubymine

How to exclude files in `log` directory from every future search without having to type exclusions in manually.

Answer (score 21):

Right click on the **folder** on the left (Project area with directories and files). Then select 'Mark Directory As...', then select 'Excluded'

Comment: I can't say exactly what happened, but now log files aren't scanned even without marking the directory as "Excluded".

Comment: There are blacklisted directories in XML confit file as well.

Answer (score 6):

You can also exclude individual files by their naming pattern, as documented here:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/excluding-files-from-project.html